# AngularJS - Scroll div container when clicking on item in different div

Tags: angularjs, scroll, location, vertical-scrolling, anchor-scroll

Context: I have a left-menu (navigator) and right-panel (content) divs. Every item from the navigator is linked to the ID of its section in the right-panel.

Problem: I'm trying to scroll the right panel to the corresponding section when clicking on the menu item from the navigation panel.

I am doing it with **anchorScroll()** and **locator.hash()** functions. It works, but it scrolls the whole page (navigation and content).

I have created two controllers: One for the parent (including the navigator) and other for the container (the one I want to scroll). When I click in the item from the menu, I am changing a variable within the scope.

Then, from the child scope, I am watching that variable, performing the scroll with

html:

```
html:

<!-- Navigation Panel -->
<div id="helpNavigatorPanel">
    <ul>
      <li ng-repeat="(value, item) in list" ng-click="setCurrentItem (item.title)">
        <a style="helpNavigationItems" href="#">{{item.title}}</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>

 <div id="helpContentPanel"ng-controller="contentHelpController" >

    <div id="scrollablePanel">
      <!-- List of help elements -->   
      <ul>
        <li ng-repeat="some in list">
          <div id="{{some.title}}" style="margin-top: 3px; padding: 10px; border: 1px solid lightGrey;">
             ...
            </div>
          </div>
        </li>
      </ul>      
    </div>    
</div>
```

js:

Scope parent:

```
 $scope.setCurrentItem = function (currentItemID){
                  $scope.currentItemID = currentItemID;
                }
```

Scope child:

```
$scope.$watch('currentItemID', function (divDestinyID) {
                    $location.hash(divDestinyID);
                    $anchorScroll();
                });
```

The problem is that the whole page is scrolled.

Any idea ?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

A possible solution is to make your "child" into a directive. That way, you can scroll on the element, rather than the entire page

*content-help.directive.js*

```
angular
    .module('appModule')
    .directive('contentHelp', contentHelp);

function contentHelp() {
    var directive = {
        bindToController: true,
        controller: ContentHelpController,
        controllerAs: 'vm',
        restrict: 'EA',
        scope: {
            list: '=',
            currentItemId: '='
        },
        templateUrl: 'contentPanel.html'
    };
    return directive;
}

ContentHelpController.$inject = ['$scope', '$element'];
/* @ngInject */
function ContentHelpController ($scope, $element) {
    var vm = this;

    $scope.$watch(function() {
        return vm.currentItemId;
    }, onIdChange);

    ////

    function onIdChange(newId) {
        if(newId) {
            var idElement = $element.find('#' + newId);
            $element.animate({
                scrollTop: idElement.offset().top
            });
        }
    }
}
```

*contentPanel.html*

```
<div id="scrollablePanel">
    <!-- List of help elements -->
    <ul>
        <li ng-repeat="some in vm.list">
            <div id="{{::some.title}}" style="margin-top: 3px; padding: 10px; border: 1px solid lightGrey;">
               ...
            </div>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

*html*

```
<!-- Navigation Panel -->
<div id="helpNavigatorPanel">
    <ul>
        <li ng-repeat="(value, item) in list" ng-click="setCurrentItem (item.title)">
            <a style="helpNavigationItems" href="#">{{item.title}}</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
<div id="helpContentPanel" ng-controller="contentHelpController">
    <content-help list="list" current-item-id="currentItemId"></content-help>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. I do understand what you are saying, and it's great! 
It is a good work, but for any reason it does not scroll. In goes into onIdChange with the newId, it creates well the idElement  (even clicking in the debugger it is accesed in the DOM), but the scroll is not working ... 
I see it enters several times into $watch function returning the id, but nothing happens. I have seen in other posts a timer is necessary. 
I tried to put it, but nothing ...... 

I'm sorry if it is something obvious that I'm not seeing, I'm starging with Angular ...

Comment: So did you wrap the animate with a `$timeout`? For example `$timeout(function() { /*animate code here*/ });`

Comment: I finally managed it with css putting fix position to the navigation (left panel) on the left, and putting the whole div into an iframe. Thank you for the help!